# OnCollisionEnter() not working in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object with a mesh collider and a prefab with sphere collider. I want the instance of the prefab to be destroyed if the two collide.

I wrote the following in a script:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
{
    if (c == target)
        Destroy(transform.gameObject);
    print("something");                   // Doesn't get printed
}
```

But it is not working. I have tried toggling `isTrigger` on both the objects.

Comment: Are you sure the colliders are entering/hitting each other?

Comment: What type is `target`? I don't think `c==target` will ever be `true`, but you should still get your message printed. You might be looking for `c.gameObject == target`. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html

Comment: the colliders are crossing each other, I saw from different angle in Scene View.

Answer (score 52):

I had the same problem of `OnCollisionEnter` not being called and found this question.

For me, the problem was that I was making a 2D game so the answer is to use the `OnCollisionEnter2D` function instead.

Comment: No one mentioned this on the whole internet except you.

Comment: Thank you! And the `Collsion collsion` argument has to be a `Collision2D` too.

Comment: I've been looking and looking and here my heroes are... holy moly.

Comment: Narrowstrife mentioned that OnTriggerEnter also needs a 2D suffix

Answer (score 45):

Have a look at [this table](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

If you want your `OnCollisionEnter` to be called make sure:

(a) Both objects have a collider attached.

(b) None of the objects is a trigger collider (this will issue OnTrigger function & not OnCollisionEnter)

(c) One of the objects (doesn't matter which of them) is a rigid, non kinematic & non static object (the second don't have to be a rigid body).

(d) Due to computational difficulties MeshCollider might have hard times colliding with other mesh collider, use them with caution.

(e) Make sure both the objects are in the same layer (or at least that they collide in scene settings).

(f) If you are working in 2d - `OnCollisionEnter2D` will be called, rename your function.

[image: example colider configuration]

Comment: This is why Unity is Shit
Thanks for the answer anyway!
Its time to get another Engine!

Comment: I always forget (c) whenever I'm doing script heave collisions.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure one of them has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached. Taken from the Unity docs:

> When a collision between two Colliders occurs and **if at least one of them has a Rigidbody attached**, three collision messages are sent out to the objects attached to them. These events can be handled in scripting, and allow you to create unique behaviors with or without making use of the built-in NVIDIA PhysX engine.

From here: [Unity3D MeshCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-MeshCollider.html)

Comment: I added non-Kinematic Rigidbody to the object with no gravity. Some error came out that said:
Actor::updateMassFromShapes: Compute mesh inertia tensor failed for one of the actor's mesh shapes! Please change mesh geometry or supply a tensor manually!

Comment: In my project, the sphere is stationary while the other object moves only because it is a child of another object, which is moved only by transforms and rotations.

Comment: The mesh shapes error may mean you have a mesh which can't be converted to a good physics rigidbody. Can you replace the mesh with a primitve to see if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the OnTriggerEnter() method and setting a collider on the object to a trigger?

If it doesn't need to tell what object its colliding with you could do a simple

```
void OnTriggerEnter(){
    Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
```

Edit:

Also I have done OnCollision like this

```
private string hitobject;

void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision hit)
{
    hitobject = hit.gameObject.tag;
    if(hitobject == "Plane")
    {
        isgrounded = true;
    }
}
```

None of the objects are triggers and they don't need rigid bodies to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The box collider wasn't as big as the collision object. Setting the x and z values to 2 units fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot under any circumstances enter a collider if is trigger is set to false. It's impossible. You **will** be stopped before entering the collider.

Comment: Sorry. Kinda upset when I posted this. It took about 12 hours to figure out. I ended up watching over 25 tutorials. NONE of them said you can't use OnCollisionEnter() with Character Controller. That was my issue. Sad that answer can't be found with a Google Search.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).