# New to Unity3D; unable to collide two simple objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an OOTB terrain (GameObject > 3D Object > Terrain)
    -Terrain Collider component
I have an OOTB sphere (GameObject > 3D Object > Sphere)
    -Sphere Collider component
I have this script attached to the sphere:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter()
    {
        // do something
    }
```

The sphere intersects the terrain; code does not trigger.

Why? What do I need to have them collide? I tried having the sphere hit a cube and it won't work either.

Comment: I take it the Sphere has a RigidBody attached?

Comment: No it doesn't have a rigidbody attached... I don't want it to have a rigidbody...

Comment: Please review the [appropriate documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) about when collisions are actually registered. The chart at the bottom should have all the information you need. (You're going to have a hard time if you don't want to use Rigidbodies at all.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnCollisionEnter() not working in Unity3D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281385/oncollisionenter-not-working-in-unity3d)

Comment: Are you trying to have a collision or a trigger, what is the purpose of the intersection? More code would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

As they said in the comments, you need a **Rigidbody** to detect the collisions, if you don't want the object to be affected by the physics of unity just check **isKinematic**